# Error with extra { in PHP elseif statement

Tags: php

Having trouble locating the problem in this elseif

Code checker suggests an extra } however I cannot find it

```
if (get_field('job_salary') == "Competitive") {
    echo "Competitive";
} elseif (get_field('job_salary') == "P.A") {
    echo the_field('job_salary_singular');
} elseif (get_field('job_salary') == "P.A Range"){
    echo "£" . the_field('job_salary_range_start') . " - " . thefield('job_salary_range_end');
} elseif (get_field('job_salary') == "Per Day"){
    echo "£" . thefield('job_salary_day_rate') == " per day";
} elseif (get_field('job_salary') == "Per Day Range"){
    echo "£" . the_field('job_salary_day_range_start') . " - " . the_field('job_salary_day_range_end') . " pd"
}
```

Comment: I see you either didn't get the PHP error message with the exact nature and location of the error, or you decided it was not relevant to your issue. In either case, feel free to ask for help on how to configure PHP to get that information or how to read it, but please don't use Stack Overflow as spell checker.

Comment: Are you using an IDE? If not, I recommend it - any of NetBeans, Eclipse, PHPStorm (and possibly others) should all find this issue even before the code is run.

Comment: You guys are a bit harsh. If she KNEW this was a typo she wouldn't have posted this here. I have been programming over 30 years and sometimes a second set of eyes helps. This post didn't hurt anyone and many of us are glad to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no semi-colon on your last 'echo' line. :) Therefore, the last } appears to be extra.